# The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I load my solution up this morning, and it no longer compiles and runs, it was working fine yesterday.

It now has the warning

> "Warning  1   The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation,
>   so it will skip compiling.    C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets    95  5   MPinUniversal"

This morning for some reason Visual Studio said my "trial" license was going to expire in 5 days which is obsurd as it's not a trial copy, so I logged in again and the warning went away, but now this.  No idea if it's related but I need this to work..

Nick.

Comment: Do the TypeScript files have the build action "TypeScriptCompile"? You can check this in Visual Studio by right clicking a file and then select properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay false alarm, the warning wasn't the cause of my problem, it was a syntax error in a .java file, the warning occurs as I have no TypeScript files to compile anyway, as it suggests.