# Error: The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, typescript

Creating new blank project of Cordova tools template by VS2013 and building interrupted giving the following message.

> Warning 1 Acquiring Cordova Tools. Any build cancellation
>   requests will be processed after acquisition has completed.    `BlankCordovaApp2`
>
> Warning 2 The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for
>   compilation, so it will skip compiling. `C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets`
>   95    5    BlankCordovaApp2

I tried to run repair installation and also remove vs and install again but not useful.

What is the solution?

Comment: Could be a duplicate of: [The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116936/the-typescript-compiler-was-given-no-files-for-compilation)

Answer (score 0):

For warning #2 it is unlikely that your Cordova app actually has any TypeScript files--the template not supposed to have TypeScript and you probably won't be writing any TypeScript. So treat this as information only, it doesn't impact your build.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this warning you can remove the `<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" />` line in your .csproj file (in this case it might be a .jsproj btw). You can just open this in your favorite text editor.

Offcourse if you plan to use TypeScript you can always add it back in.

Haven't seen warning one ever, but I guess it goes away after it downloaded everything for the first time?

Comment: Thanks for yr replay but the issue still fire

Answer (score 0):

Tools>Options>Projects and Solutions>Build and Run>Set MSBuild project build output verbosity= Diagnostic

now you can see why/where it crash

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error, and I fixed that now, when I check my system environment variables,

```
System Properties -> Advanced -> environment variables -> Path
```

PS: the Path is too long, so I edit that to short